# Dealing with an httpclient that brings the next request to do until finish

Tags: angular, sharepoint, httpclient

When calling with Sharepoint API a huge list that exceeds 100 rows or the ones you put in $top=100. You get the fields of the list and a __next variable. This __next variable contains a string to the next page address you need to query for the subsequent elements of the list.

My problem lies in my incapability to perform http.get request synchronously so there is no way to know if next has ended or not.

I've tried recursive methods, build my own custom RxJS operator and building an Observable that calls subscriber.next bu I always get stumbled with the subsequent requests.

```js
getExpedienteFromUrl(httpUrl?: string): Observable<ExpedienteListAndNextQuery> {
    const urlAddress = (httpUrl ? httpUrl : this.urlSharepointAPIExpedientes );
    return this.http.get<D>(urlAddress, {
      headers: {
        accept: 'application/json;odata=verbose'
      }
    }).pipe(
      map(x => this.mapExpedientesOfObserver(x) ),
      this.getExpedientesPipe()
    );
}

getExpedientesPipe(): Observable <IExpediente[]> {
    return ($source: Observable<ExpedienteListAndNextQuery>) => {
      return new Observable<IExpediente[]>(subscriber => {
        $source.subscribe(
          data => {
            const expedientes: IExpediente[] = data.Expedientes;
            const next: string = data.Next;
            subscriber.next(expedientes);
            if (next) {
              // call to this.getExpedienteFromUrl(next) [Async]
              // so if this where in a do while the following next will always 
              // be undefined
            }
          },
          err => subscriber.error(err),
          () => subscriber.complete()
        );
      });
    };
  }
```

Comment: Can you please check if this link can help you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56520156/nested-observable-with-unknown-nesting-depth

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know there was such an operator pipe. It saved me an ugly load more button which was my last choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, @user2457680.

I'll post how my code ended up being for my question. I hope, someone else finds it useful.

```
getExpediente(): Observable<IExpediente> {
    return this.http.get<D>(this.urlSharepointAPIExpedientes, {
      headers: {
        accept: 'application/json;odata=verbose'
      }
    }).pipe(
      map(x => this.mapExpedientesOfObserver(x) ),
      expand(x => (x.Next ? this.getExpedienteFromUrl(x.Next) : EMPTY)),
      concatMap(x => x.Expedientes)
    );
  }

  private getExpedienteFromUrl(httpUrl: string): Observable<ExpedienteListAndNextQuery> {
    return this.http.get<D>(httpUrl, {
      headers: {
        accept: 'application/json;odata=verbose'
      }
    }).pipe(
      map(x => this.mapExpedientesOfObserver(x))
    );
  }

export interface D {
  d: Results;
}

export interface Results {
  results: SharepointExpediente[];
  __next: string;
}
```

Map function only transforms SharePoint variables into human-like variables after all SharePoint enjoys using word_x020_word_x020_word which maintaining either for myself or for others would be a nightmare.